# app.config separation of implementation

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am interested in the following scenario. There exists a class library that contains a generic repository interface named IRepository. The library also contains multiple implementations of the same interface e.g. UserRepository, ItemRepository and so on. Also I do not able to add external libraries like Unity or other DI containers. My question are:

1. Is there a way to map implementations of the interface via
   configuration file (e.g.  for the purpose of a repository factory)?
2. Is it posible to make a configuration file that holds a path to classes that implement interfaces?
3. If such a possibility exists, is it also possible to create a class that consumes that information (e.g. Factory that uses a specific implementation to generate a repository)?

Comment: Some IOC containers provides configuration through xml. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am sorry for beeing unclear. I will edit the question to provide more context

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use Unity container anyway. It allows to do something like that in config file:

```
<container>
  <register type="ILogger" mapTo="EventLogLogger" /> 
</container>
```

Or you can do the same by yourself reading config sections and creating instances using reflection at application start up

Comment: What if external dependncies are not allowed ( installing unity etc.) ? Any idea is much appriciated.

Comment: I think the only way in this case is implement container by yourself: create config sections with interface-implementation mapping, read this on app start and create instances using reflection. Is it possible in your case?